# I have 3 forms and one submit button and I am just receiving information from 1 form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am putting information in my forms and I'm just receiving 1 from the form number 3 not the others.

Here is my code in the page

What should I do to solve this problem? Could someone please helps me out with this..

```
// my code to the forms in the page
  <div style="margin-left:110px;float:left !important ;clear:both;">
<?php

echo '
<form method="post" action="testing.php" id="form1">
<textarea style="height:150px;width:250px;" name="message"></textarea>

</form>
';
?>
</div>
<div>
<?php

echo '
<form method="post" action="testing2.php" id="form2">
<textarea style="margin-left:80px;height:150px;width:250px;" name="message">Write your opinon here</textarea>

</form>
';
?>

</div>
<div>

<?php
echo '
<form method="post" action="testing3.php" id="form3">
<textarea style="margin-left:80px;height:150px;width:250px;" name="message"></textarea>

</form>
';
?>
</div>
```

My javascript for the forms:

```
 <script>
            submitForms = function() {
                document.forms["form1"].submit();
                document.forms["form2"].submit();
                document.forms["form3"].submit();
                return true;
            }
        </script>

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitForms()" />
```

and the **php** code for my forms is below (I have the same code for the other forms):

```
//php code to connect to mysql



<?php
$message=$_POST['message'];
$con=mysqli_connect();
$sql="insert into textarea values('$message')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{echo "Thanks for your opinoin";}
?>
<!DOCETYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {

    text-align:center;
padding-top:300px;
font-size:40px;
color:white;
font-style:oblique;

}


</style>
</head>

<body background="hero.jpg" text="">
<?php

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What should I do??

Comment: You can do this with using ajax.

Comment: Check my answer @Ahmad Saidan

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 separate forms, and only first .submit() in javascript works.
Either merge everything to one form(you still can have 3 buttons and check what is pressed) or write ajax code what submit 3 different forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code was Correct if you use this code:

```
<script>
            submitForms = function() {
                document.forms["form1"].submit();
                document.forms["form2"].submit();
                document.forms["form3"].submit();
                return true;
            }
        </script>

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitForms()" />
```

your html form should like this code :

```
<form method="post" action="testing1.php" name="form1">
<form method="post" action="testing2.php" name="form2">
<form method="post" action="testing3.php" name="form3">
```

Or You can use like this code:

```
submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
    document.getElementById("form3").submit();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your code's action links reference to three different locations, plus each form needs to have a unique submit button. if you need to get the inputs of each form then set an id for that submit button and the in your php code check if it's set.
like so:

```
<form method="post" action="testing2.php" id="form2">
<textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit btn" id="submit_id">
</form>
```

then in php do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_id'])){

}
```